# What's the point of setting individual file permissions if no one can access/view your directory anyway?

Tags: permissions, directory, umask

Scenario:

1. I have a file inside my ~ directory called `file.txt`.
2. My ~ directory has it's permissions set to **700**.
3. My file has permissions set to **664**.

The problem is, no one can even access it because my home directory won't allow it.

So, as long as I keep my home directory permissions fixed to **700** only me and root can access those files, regardless of their individual permissions, right?

If so, why bother set a file to **600** instead of the standard **644**?

In other words, is there a point to change the file mode creation mask to **600** for that kind of files (assuming you have more than one user in your system and that your ~ directory permissions is set to **700**)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139150/360892)

> If you create a file underneath ~ which is readable by others and then create a hard link to this file in an accessible path, they'll be able to read it regardless of the permissions on ~.

Answer (score 0):

That would be true if you set your home directory permission to 700. But that is not the default setting. On Ubuntu server a new user's home directory gets 'drwxr-xr-x'. That gives a good reason to set some individual permissions for your files and directories.

Comment: I believe you are right about Ubuntu desktop and all debian-based distributions for that matter. What confuses me is the fact that am running Arch Linux and the completely unchanged umask is setting the permissions to 700 by default.